# ORA-01722: invalid number exception in update

Tags: java

I am performing this update query in java

`String sql="update book_details set book_inv=book_inv-1 where BOOKISBN=?`

and getting

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number exception

Comment: Have you googled what ORA-01722 means?

Comment: yes Gavin I checked its being thrown due to attempted conversion of char string to number here book_inv colunb is number only.

Answer (score 0):

Having quickly googled ORA-01722 I would guess oracles sql parser is trying to convert `book_inv` to a number in the expression "`book_inv-1`"
Perhaps its as simple as changing it to `book_inv - 1`

Comment: even changing this is not resolving the error .How can I change it to number. Can I use TO_Number function

Comment: what type is BOOKISBN? could it be that it is numeric and you are passing a non-numeric value to it in the prepared statement?

Comment: BOOKISBN is of varchar type and I am getting it as this type of value 9034534-83.Is there any other way to perform same update.

Comment: The sql looks fine to me, so without seeing the rest of the query, and knowing how you are using it (I am guess prepared statement) the only numeric in there is book_inv.... so I can only assume that book_inv isn't a numeric type.

Comment: ok I think you are correct I am getting ISBN on click of check box and sending it to servlet but not sending the BOOKINV field thus might be causing this error .Can you please tell how to pass multiple values from jsp to servlet .BOOKISBN is passed like this       <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="${bookBean1.bookISBN}"></td>

Comment: I haven't done pure JSP's for years, so I wouldn't like to guess, you should do a search of stack overflow, or ask that as a separate question rather than confuse this one.